# "Into" vs. "Inside" vs. "Under"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which of these three sentences is correct?

> He snuck a souvenir into his shirt.
>
> He snuck a souvenir under his shirt.
>
> He snuck a souvenir inside his shirt.

Comment: Shirts don't really have an "inside", though *in* would be OK.

Comment: @user3169 - Shirts don't have an inside?  That's news to me and [the many authors that have used the phrase "inside his shirt"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22inside+his+shirt%22).

Comment: @Fizza, Any of your proposed prepositions is correct. However, there is still controversy concerning the past tense of the verb "to sneak." Although "snuck" is heard frequently in the United States, it is not considered standard usage elsewhere. In formal or business usage, it is usually better to use "sneaked."

Comment: @stangdon You can use "inside", but it really means "under". Interesting several of these are about 'her touching him inside his shirt'. Guess I'm reading the wrong books.

Comment: [Many people](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/252040/2637) would say that ***snuck*** is "dialectal, slangy", so to them it probably wouldn't make much difference which preposition you used (any preference on that front would be less than their preference for ***sneaked***, or perhaps a different verb, such as ***slipped, secreted, hid***).

Comment: As an American, I think "sneaked" sounds weird.

Comment: I'm in the same dialectal group as @Catija—"sneaked" sounds to me like a mistaken over-regularization: "First he sneaked down the stairs, and then he goed back up." Obviously, it would be important to know your audience when deciding between the two.

Answer (score 2):

All are possible, but they mean slightly different things.

- I would use "into" if he was sneaking the item **into his shirt from
  the front/neck** (as with a shirt that buttons).
- I would use "under" if he was sneaking it up **under the hem of the shirt**.
- "Inside" sounds to me as if he had *already* hidden a souvenir in his shirt (alongside his body) and was trying to sneak it somewhere, but in that case I would expect a phrase indicating where he was sneaking the souvenir: "He snuck the souvenir *out of the shop* inside his shirt."

Some examples, that I think make these distinctions clearer (emphases mine):

> With a sly grin, the girl tucked the money **into** her blouse. —[*The
>   Patriot Paradox* by William Esmont](https://books.google.com/books?id=7Lsw272QKeEC&lpg=PT5&dq=%22tucked%20the%20money%20into%20her%20blouse%22&pg=PT5#v=onepage&q=%22tucked%20the%20money%20into%20her%20blouse%22&f=false)
>
> She stuffed the pillow **under** her shirt and examined her profile in an
>   attempt to see what she'd look like fat with a baby. —[*Enchanged
>   Heart* by Felicia Mason](https://books.google.com/books?id=RjSXBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA395&ots=42KgwQGKdz&dq=%22stuffed%20the%20pillow%20under%20her%20shirt%22&pg=PA395#v=onepage&q=%22stuffed%20the%20pillow%20under%20her%20shirt%22&f=false)
>
> Before he walked in the boardinghouse, he tucked the small puppy
>   **inside** his shirt. —[*Timberlake* by Grey Stone](https://books.google.com/books?id=1-NrNWXTv2MC&lpg=PA289&dq=puppy%20inside%20his%20shirt&pg=PA289#v=onepage&q=puppy%20inside%20his%20shirt&f=false)

Note that in the third example (inside) it's unclear whether he tucks the puppy in from the top or the bottom; what's emphasized is where the puppy ends up.

Answer (score -1):

'Inside' and 'into' both imply, to me, that you are sneaking something into the fibers of the shirt fabric. They're not incorrect grammatically, and if you said them someone would know what you meant, but 'under' is probably the best choice here.